# how to fix output data from file so the matrix is stacked instead of in 1 line

Tags: python, matrix, thonny

```
result = [[sum(a*b for a,b in zip(matrix1_row,matrix2_col)) for matrix2_col in zip(*matrix2)] for matrix1_row in matrix1]    

outf = open("multimatrix.txt", "w")
outf.write(str(result)[1:-1])
outf.close()
```

this gives me  [1750, 1029], [2252, 754] in the output file however I want it to look like this

1750 1029

2252 754

im guessing its because of the way i did the matrix multiplication however i couldnt get numpy to work in thonny

Comment: This doesn't look like java code. Please remove the java tag.

Comment: Your `result` is a list of lists and calling `str()` on a list of list, will give you that representation like `[[1750, 1029], [2252, 754]]` (you're just clipping off `[]` with the `[1:-1]` bit). If you want to write a different representation, you'll need to write it yourself (for example with something like `for line in result: outf.write(' '.join(line))`)

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 ways you can do this in python.
First you can loop through your list of list and write each line to the file.

```
with open("multimatrix.txt", "w") as f:
    for line in result:
    f.write(str(line)[1:-1]+'\n')
```

Second you can create the string you want to write using list comprehension and write it all at once.

```
with open("multimatrix.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write('\n'.join([str(x)[1:-1] for x in result]))
```